# Troubleshooting Error in Flutter Weather Widget - 'DateTime?' Argument Type

Tags: flutter, dart

I prepared such a method based on the widget https://pub.dev/packages/weather, which retrieves data from: https://openweathermap.org/current

```
bool isNight(Weather weather) {
    return DateTime.now().isAfter(weather.sunset) || DateTime.now().isBefore(weather.sunrise);
  }
```

Unfortunately get an error

Error: The argument type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime' because 'DateTime?' is nullable and 'DateTime' isn't.
'DateTime' is from 'dart:core'.
return DateTime.now().isAfter(weather.sunset) || DateTime.now().isBefore(weather.sunrise);

What could I be doing wrong?

Prepare a logic gate of the type whether the actual is nighttime

Answer (score 0):

isAfter and isBefore takes a DateTime type as a parameter but weather.sunset and weather.sunrise is DateTime? type. You need to check before that line if weather.sunset and weather.sunrise is null.

```
if (weather.sunset==null || weather.sunrise==null) return false; //or throw an exception.
return DateTime.now().isAfter(weather.sunset) || DateTime.now().isBefore(weather.sunrise);
```

Since you already checked if weather.sunset and weather.sunrise is null so in the next line they cannot be null so Dart will promote their type to DateTime. If you're certain that weather.sunset and weather.sunrise will never be null you can add ! before them without if check. But if they're ever null, you're application will crash.

```
return DateTime.now().isAfter(weather.sunset!) || DateTime.now().isBefore(weather.sunrise!);
```

Read more about it here: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety